# MongoDB user new role vanish after few seconds

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a problem with MongoDB database. Each time I try to add role to new database to existing user it vanish after few seconds.

```
current user:
    {
    _id: 'admin.xxx',
    user: 'xxx',
    db: 'ddd',
    roles: [
      { role: 'dbAdminAnyDatabase', db: 'ddd' },
      { role: 'readWriteAnyDatabase', db: 'ddd' },
      { role: 'userAdminAnyDatabase', db: 'ddd' }
    ],
    userId: new UUID("123456"),
    mechanisms: [ 'SCRAM-SHA-1' ]
  },
```

next try to add role for new (existing) database:

```
db.grantRolesToUser('xxx', [{ role: 'readWrite', db: 'new_database' }]);
```

I get "OK" return message

check user roles and it's ok:

```
 {
    _id: 'admin.xxx',
    user: 'xxx',
    db: 'ddd',
    roles: [
      { role: 'dbAdminAnyDatabase', db: 'ddd' },
      { role: 'userAdminAnyDatabase', db: 'ddd' },
      { role: 'readWrite', db: 'new_database' },
      { role: 'readWriteAnyDatabase', db: 'ddd' }
    ],
    userId: new UUID("123456"),
    mechanisms: [ 'SCRAM-SHA-1' ]
  },
```

But after a few seconds check again and new role is gone:

```
current user:
    {
    _id: 'admin.xxx',
    user: 'xxx',
    db: 'ddd',
    roles: [
      { role: 'dbAdminAnyDatabase', db: 'ddd' },
      { role: 'readWriteAnyDatabase', db: 'ddd' },
      { role: 'userAdminAnyDatabase', db: 'ddd' }
    ],
    userId: new UUID("123456"),
    mechanisms: [ 'SCRAM-SHA-1' ]
  },
```

Should I do something more after new role action?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this? I am running into the same, running on DigitalOcean.